# Is there any replacement for tf.random_gamma in pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm converting a TensorFlow repository to PyTorch code. I came across this line of code:

```
tf.squeeze(tf.random_gamma(shape =(self.n_sample,),alpha=self.alpha+tf.to_float(self.B)))
```

I would like to know the equivalent of **tf.random_gamma** in PyTorch. I think `torch.distributions.gamma.Gamma` doesn't work the same way.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please have a try and read the doc or try coding it.
Then give more details, and a minimal reproducible example with code you wrote yet / sample data / and full error messages
about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help.
See [MRE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `torch.distributions.gamma.Gamma` can be used in this case. Here is an example:

```
import torch
from torch.distributions.gamma import Gamma


def random_gamma(shape, alpha, beta=1.0):
  alpha = torch.ones(shape) * torch.tensor(alpha)
  beta = torch.ones(shape) * torch.tensor(beta)
  gamma_distribution = Gamma(alpha, beta)

  return gamma_distribution.sample()

print(random_gamma(shape=(10,), alpha=3.0))
```

Output:

```
tensor([2.7673, 1.5498, 6.5191, 5.2923, 3.3204, 3.9286, 1.4163, 1.2400, 3.9661, 1.7663])
```

The difference is that `torch.distributions.gamma.Gamma` requires complete tensors for alpha and beta instead of shape+values like it is in TF. Also, TF version has default value 1 for beta which I tried to imitate in the example code.

It makes sense to create distribution instance once though in case if the function will be used multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @Serhii. I was thinking using a function could slow down my optimization, as the reparameterization technique I'm implementing itself is already complex on its own. So, I was wondering if there is a library that works the same way as **tf.random_gamma** in PyTorch. Again, thank you.